# HTML CSS, Link definition, remove border off image in link

Tags: css, inheritance, hyperlink

In my page I have two types of links, text links and image links.
for text links, I have defined following CSS rules:

```
a:link, a:visited{
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #ccb771;
}   
a:hover, a:active{
    color: #333300;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #333300;
    padding-bottom: 0.25em;
}
```

For text links everything is OK! but for image links, underline is added when mouse goes over image. I added this code to define new rule for image links:

```
.bodyimage a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active{
border: none;
padding-bottom: 0px;
```

}

but this rule overrides previous links and underline do not show for text links.
What should I do?

Sorry for my horrible English!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the border is assigned to the (hover) link. In order to remove that when there's an image present you would need a parent selector, which doesn't exist,  i.e. you would need to be saying - if this link contains an `img`, remove the border from the parent `a`

parent selectors are often wished for, and are possible with JS :)

The way around it is to classify (add class to) one of the options to target either `a:hover` or `a:hover img`

kind of like this..

**CSS:**

```
a:link, a:visited{
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #ccb771;
}

a:hover, a:active{
    color: #333300;
    padding-bottom: 0.25em;
}

a img {border: 0;}

a.txt:hover, a.txt:active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #333300;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a class="txt" href="#">text link</a> - <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="" width="100" height="100"></a>
```

If you've less image links it might be better to classify the links which contain images..

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your CSS:

```
img
{
    border:0;
}
```

And remove your `bodyimage` class.  If this doesn't work, try:

```
img
{
    border:0 !important;
    padding:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have img{border:none;}. I changed border to 0 and removed the class but first rule apply to my image links.

Comment: @Hesam, I've updated the answer, try adding the important tag

Comment: Thanks for your follow up, but unfortunately it didn't work. I checked in all browsers but still have underline.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm missing something, but is there a reason you are using border-bottom to add an underline to the text? if you use text-decoration:underline, your text gets underlined while images don't. Isn't that what you want?

If you want this effect only when you are hovering over the link, you want:

```
a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #ccb771;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration:underline;
  color: #333300;
}
a img {
  border:none;
}
```

That should give you the colours you wanted, and underline the text while leaving the images underlined.

Comment: text-decoration wouldn't give a **2px** underline with some padding between it and the text.. use of borders instead of decoration give more flexibility

Comment: Ah ... so there was something I missed. :)

Comment: At the first time I did it but it did not have enough space or gap between line and text. The drawn underline attached to text.